# Can't change my download directory in python

Tags: python

I download images with `urllib.request.retrieve` to some python directory and it keeps saving them there, though I've changed the directory with `os.chdir()`.

Also, it shows the correct directory in `os.getcwd()` - the one that I've changed to.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show some code?  There's a couple things this could be, so it's hard to give an answer without more detail.

Comment: >>> os.chdir('/Users/user/Music/ohshi')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/user/Music/ohshi'
but still saves to some system python folder

Comment: No, the call to `retrieve`.

Comment: You probably mean [urllib.request.urlretrieve()](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).  As you can see in the linked documentation (hint!), it writes its output to a temporary file if you don't tell it explicitly where to write it.